# Uninstalling openstackclient and restore previous glance and keystone version

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-juno

I installed python-openstackclient in Juno and it did the following actions:

```
> Installing collected packages:
> keystoneauth1, python-keystoneclient,
> python-glanceclient,
> python-openstackclient                
> Found existing installation:
> python-keystoneclient 0.11.1          
> 
>     Uninstalling python-keystoneclient-0.11.1:         
> 
>       Successfully uninstalled python-keystoneclient-0.11.1          
> Found existing installation:
> python-glanceclient 0.15.0            
> 
>     Uninstalling python-glanceclient-0.15.0:           
> 
>       Successfully uninstalled python-glanceclient-0.15.0            
> Successfully installed
> keystoneauth1-2.16.0
> python-glanceclient-2.5.0
> python-keystoneclient-3.8.0
> python-openstackclient-3.4.1
```

Now I need to completely uninstall python-openstackclient and restore the previous version (and behavior) of keystone and glance.

In my "production" system I have juno without openstackclient and old version of all packages (keystone v2, glance, etc, from EPEL repository Centos 7), while in the "test" system I have juno and installed openstackclient and newer version of the packages (pip repository) . So in the near future I have to upgrade (in safe mode!) the production system from juno to mitaka and I need to test it on the test system before. This is the reason because I need to have the "same identical installation" both on test and production system.

---

UPDATE:
To avoid the use of api v3 and rollback to api v2, in the controller nodes I uninstalled all openstack python packets and reinstalled them following this procedure http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/yum/content/ch_overview.html.

I uninstalled packets through:

```
for dep in $(pip show python-openstackclient | grep Requires | sed 's/Requires: //g; s/,//g') ; do echo $dep ; done
for dep in $(pip show python-openstackclient | grep Requires | sed 's/Requires: //g; s/,//g') ; do sudo pip uninstall -y $dep ; done

pip uninstall -y python-openstackclient

yum remove openstack-keystone python-keystoneclient openstack-glance python-glanceclient python-glance-store.noarch openstack-nova-api openstack-nova-cert openstack-nova-conductor openstack-nova-console openstack-nova-novncproxy openstack-nova-scheduler python-novaclient openstack-neutron openstack-neutron-ml2 python-neutronclient openstack-dashboard httpd mod_wsgi memcached python-memcached openstack-swift-proxy python-swiftclient python-keystonemiddleware openstack-heat-api openstack-heat-api-cfn openstack-heat-engine python-heatclient openstack-ceilometer-api openstack-ceilometer-collector openstack-ceilometer-notification openstack-ceilometer-central openstack-ceilometer-alarm python-ceilometerclient python-six python-babel python-cliff python-cinderclient.noarch openstack-cinder python-cinderclient python-oslo-db openstack-swift openstack-swift-plugin-swift3 python-ceilometer
```

But when I launch `glance image-show ID-image` I had the following error:

```
raise AttributeError(k)
AttributeError: id
id
```

and I can't figure out why in the /glance/api.log appears `INFO keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Auth Token confirmed use of v3.0 apis` despite the default Juno installation uses api v2. I assume the problems are related to each other. What do you think?

Comment: Great, I have updated the question.

Comment: can any one help?

Comment: Want me to start a bounty on this, Cristiano? I am happy to if you are committed to getting a solution for it.

Comment: It looks like a Python question, so I have retagged to get more eyes on it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. `python-openstackclient` installation caused the upgrade of `python-requests` library and this is in conflicts with `python-glanceclient`. I solved by downgrading the requests library to 2.7.0, which was the previous release.